# Login to Parse cloud code using android

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In my android app I'm using *ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground()* to call my cloud function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("delete", function(request, response)
{
    Parse.User.logOut();

    Parse.User._currentUser = new Parse.User();
    Parse.User._currentUser._if=request.params.user;
    Parse.User._currentUser._sessionToken = request.params.token;

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.get(request.user)
        .then(function(user)
        {
            Parse.User._saveCurrentUser(user);
            response.success("User login valid!");      
        },
        function(err)
        {
            response.error("Login failed: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
});
```

While I've expected this to login the user, it always returns "Object not found". I'm sending the user id returned by "**user.getObjectId()**" and session "**user.getSessionToken()**".

Comment: Shouldn't it be `request.user` instead of `response.user` in your query?

Comment: yeah, sorry, seems I've made a mistake when I was pasting it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule of thumb for logging in via cloud code is to call the `logIn` function, return the session token and in the app code call the `becomeInBackground` method, like this:

In your cloud code:

```
Parse.User.logIn(username, password).then(function(user) {
    response.success(user._sessionToken);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
});
```

And then in your app code:

```
// call cloud code function that returns sessionToken

ParseUser.becomeInBackground(sessionToken, new LogInCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // log in successful
        } else {
            // log in failed
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I need the exact opposite of this, but your code provided enough information to solve the problem

Comment: Happy to help (in a weird opposite kind of way)

Comment: I logged in in the android device, but I seemed to have missed the parse function "become"

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the built in login function with parse?

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e == null)
                loginSuccessful();
            else
                loginUnSuccessful();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I know about this method, but I need to perform some actions server-side that should not be visible should the app code be decompiled

Comment: couldnt you just  call another cloud function inside your response?

Comment: The problem is that the authorization does not follow through